# How to deal with misssing values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, product, nan, missing-data

I´d like to know when we have a dataset with missing values, what´s the best way to treat them? Remove them directly or replace with zeros?

Suppose i have these dates:

| id | name | price | product_group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nd | 14.35 | care |
| 2 | nd | 10.02 | makeup |
| 3 | nd | 5.40 | nd |
| 4 | nd | 7.68 | nd |

I need to analyse the dates in the column 'product group' and tried to remove the values 'nd' using this code but it doesnt work.

```
    order['product_group'] = order['product_group'].replace('nd', np.nan)
    order['product_group'] = order['product_group'].dropna(how='any')
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove missing values for all dataframe or just for `product_group` column?

Comment: "what´s the best way to treat them?" There is no simple single answer. It depends. You have a lot of data and you have only a few missing points? The simple answer would be, drop them. But what if there is a reason they have missing values? Imagine missing data in the age column of persons. Maybe people between 20-40 are more carful about privacy. If you just drop them your data gets biased. There are a lot of ways to deal with missing data, such as drop, mean/median encoding, binning, kNN, MICE, Datawig,....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `dropna()` on the whole dataframe and just `subset` the `product_group` column:

```py
order['product_group'] = order['product_group'].replace('nd', np.nan)
order = order.dropna(subset=['product_group'])

#    id name  price product_group
# 0   1   nd  14.35          care
# 1   2   nd  10.02        makeup
```

---

As for why your version didn't work, note that when you `dropna()` on the column by itself (without assigning back), that works fine:

```py
order['product_group'].dropna()

# 0      care
# 1    makeup
# Name: product_group, dtype: object
```

But if you assign this short Series back into the full dataframe, pandas doesn't know what to do with the extra rows and just puts the `nan` values back.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to index the `'nd'` rows inside the `product_group` column, and then drop them from the original dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

i= order[(order.product_group=='nd')].index

order.drop(i)
```